# How to send Custom Message from C++ MFC to WPF C# application?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, winapi

I need to send a custom message/notification from MFC(C++) to WPF(C#) application.
There are some topics over the internet about message sending from C# to C++ application.
I have tried to implement my case followed by those articles but unable to receive message from WPF.

Whatever I have tried is given below:

**From MFC application I have tried to send a message with both PostMessage & SendMessage
But none of this can receive from WPF application.**

```
UINT deviceConnected = 0;
deviceConnected = RegisterWindowMessage(L"DEVICE_CONNECTED");
HWND dstWnd = (HWND)GetProp(GetDesktopWindow(), L"DEVICE_CONNECTED_HWND");

const char* message = "This is a custom message";
::PostMessage(dstWnd, deviceConnected, 0, (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)message);
::SendMessage(dstWnd, deviceConnected, 0, (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)message);
```

**I have also tried with WM_COPYDATA:**

```
LPCTSTR lpszString = (LPCTSTR)L"This is second message";
COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
cds.dwData = 0;
cds.cbData = sizeof(TCHAR) * (_tcslen(lpszString) + 1);
cds.lpData = (PVOID)lpszString;
::PostMessage(dstWnd, WM_COPYDATA, 0, (LPARAM)(LPVOID)&cds); 
::SendMessage(dstWnd, WM_COPYDATA, 0, (LPARAM)(LPVOID)&cds);
```

**Here below is the WPF code sample:**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);
private UInt32 deviceAttachedEvent = 0;
const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x4A;
    
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    HwndSource hwndSource = HwndSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
    if (hwndSource != null)
    {
        hwndSource.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
    }
}

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msgId, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;

    //if the deviceAttachedEvent message id has not been registered...
    if (deviceAttachedEvent == 0)
        deviceAttachedEvent  = RegisterWindowMessage("DEVICE_CONNECTED");

    if ((UInt32)msgId == deviceAttachedEvent )
    {
        //string msg = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(lParam);
        Console.WriteLine("Received message from MFC");
        //Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    if (msgId == WM_COPYDATA)
    {
        COPYDATASTRUCT cds = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
        cds = (COPYDATASTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam,typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
        if (cds.cbData > 0)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[cds.cbData];
            Marshal.Copy(cds.lpData, data, 0, cds.cbData);
            Encoding unicodeStr = Encoding.ASCII;
            char[] myString = unicodeStr.GetChars(data);
            string returnText = new string(myString);
            MessageBox.Show("ACK Received: " + returnText);
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear, what *"unable to receive message"* means. Does it fail to compile? Does it compile but fail to link? Does it compile and link but fail at runtime with an error? Does it fail without an error? Does the message actually make it through, but the data is not what you expect? Something else?

Comment: @yeasir007 Have you isolated if the problem is only related to receiving the message on WPF? i.e. have you tried from a native C/C++/MFC app to another? You may also look into alternative interprocess communication methods here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications

Comment: @IInspectable, message has been send from MFC application but this message is not received from WPF WndProg.

Comment: Have you verified, that the registered messages have the same (non-zero) value? Have you verified, whether the `HWND`s are the same on either side? Also make sure to understand, that the system does not marshal pointed-to data across process boundaries for messages outside the range 0 .. `WM_USER`. Registered messages are outside that range.

Comment: Debugged value for registered message is same from both end. How HWND can be same from both side, i didn't get your point. Can you please make it clear. And registered message value range is a positive value like 10079.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use the code to get the message sent by the C++ project (both `deviceAttachedEvent` and `WM_COPYDATA`).
I used `FindWindow(NULL,L"WPFwindow name")` to get the hwnd handle, instead of `GetProp`, so make sure you've got a correct window handle. You could use [`EnumPropsEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumpropsexa) to test if you have the property of the `"DEVICE_CONNECTED_HWND"`

For WindowMessage `deviceConnected`:
You are sending a pointer in the current process, another process usually does not have permission to directly access this address. You need to use [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) to read the string data in this address.

In addition, please pay attention to the char set of the project. `L"***"` does not need to be cast to `LPCTSTR` if char set is UNICODE, and use `"***"` if the char set is Multi-Byte Character Set. Or use `TEXT("")` macro.

Also, you sent a wide byte string `L"This is second message"`, and then set `Encoding.ASCII` when reading, this will truncate the string like:

[image]

So my sample is:
C++:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
int main()
{
    UINT deviceConnected = 0;
    deviceConnected = RegisterWindowMessage(L"DEVICE_CONNECTED");
    HWND dstWnd = FindWindow(NULL,L"MainWindow");

    const wchar_t* message = TEXT("This is a custom message");
    ::SendMessage(dstWnd, deviceConnected, 0, (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)message);

    LPCTSTR lpszString = TEXT("This is second message");
    COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
    cds.dwData = 0;
    cds.cbData = sizeof(TCHAR) * (_tcslen(lpszString) + 1);
    cds.lpData = (PVOID)lpszString;

    ::SendMessage(dstWnd, WM_COPYDATA, 0, (LPARAM)(LPVOID)&cds);

}
```

in wpf:

```
   private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msgId, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;

        //if the deviceAttachedEvent message id has not been registered...
        if (deviceAttachedEvent == 0)
            deviceAttachedEvent = RegisterWindowMessage("DEVICE_CONNECTED");

        if ((UInt32)msgId == deviceAttachedEvent)
        {
            //OpenProcess + PROCESS_VM_READ
            //ReadProcessMemory + lParam
            Console.WriteLine("Received message from MFC");
        }

        if (msgId == WM_COPYDATA)
        {
            COPYDATASTRUCT cds = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
            cds = (COPYDATASTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
            if (cds.cbData > 0)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[cds.cbData];
                Marshal.Copy(cds.lpData, data, 0, cds.cbData);
                Encoding unicodeStr = Encoding.Unicode;
                char[] myString = unicodeStr.GetChars(data);
                string returnText = new string(myString);
                MessageBox.Show("ACK Received: " + returnText);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Drake. This Window handler was the actual problem.